# What's special in July 26th and why is it used in examples for Expires header so often?

Tags: php, headers

I've noticed that July 26th (my birthday) is used really often in various PHP examples related to preventing http caching using `Expires` header, like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398714/cache-issue-with-private-networking-stream

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833305/how-to-expire-page-in-php-when-user-logout

http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/81945/

What's special in that date?

Comment: Interestingly it's _not_ the example date on either the [HTTP/1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Expires) or the [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) RFCs, both use `Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT` (...and yes, it was a Thursday ;).

Comment: Related: [Why is the default cache expires header Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT? What is the significance of this date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3809947/99456)

Comment: From looking around, '7/26/97' is whats in the PHP docs for header output.  Have no idea if thats the cause (people copy/pasting), or just another case.

Comment: Could it be [Sysadmin Day](http://sysadminday.com/)? It fell on July 26th in 2002 (and also in 1996, if Sysadmin Day had been celebrated in that year already... which AFAIK was not the case).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably somebody did that as an example of a cache expires a long time ago and then everybody copied it.  Interestingly it's often expressed as "Mon, 26 July 1997", but the actual date occurred on a Saturday.  It's not that interesting in terms of UTC seconds (seconds since 1970) since it is 869893200. Maybe it's just an example of CTRL-C/CTRL-V coding?

Answer (score 4):

Only thing I could find was the release of Mac OS 8. Not related to CSS release dates, HTML, XML, PHP, Javascript, Internet Explorer, Nescape Navigator, Apache Foundation, MySQL, or anything else relevant I could wrack my brain for. I suspect it's probably someone's kid's birthday or anniversary or something. In short, it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) example tutorial has the date. So its a copy paste and the developer forgot to update the expiry date.

[image]

Comment: They clearly copied it from the PHP Manual page.